# Caulking a baseboard - which bit do you paint?

Tags: painting, baseboard, caulking

If I am using decorator's caulk to fill the gap at the top of the baseboard, I am left with a bead of caulk. I know I need to paint the caulk, once cured, to stop it attracting dust. So how do I paint the bead - do I paint it with the same paint as the baseboard, or with the same paint as the wall? Or half and half?!

What is the accepted way? What looks the best?

Thank you

Comment: Ideally you don't actually have an actual bead. You should've tooled it out to leave a shape that's not much different from what tight baseboard would look like. If you have an actual bead, you have a painting challenge. Do whatever hides it best. I'd consider slicing it flat with a utility knife and new blade.

Comment: @isherwood Yeah, I might try and cut it out and start again... :(

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to paint it the colour of the baseboard.  I tend to use Satinwood, and the thicker paint helps to mask the bead itself better.  It does require a steady hand as you really don't want to be accidentally painting that on to your wall (I hate masking tape).

As previous commenters have noted, the bead should not be all that thick.  When I install baseboard (or skirting board, as we call it in the UK), I try to use an adhesive like No More Nails as it saves filling or covering the nail holes.
If you are using nails then I would definitely suggest using a couple more to ensure you keep that gap as small as possible

Answer (score 1):

Match the baseboard, since it's an extension of the baseboard and not the wall. Sure an extremely keen eye will notice the baseboard's thicker in spots, but almost any eye will notice the wall's bulging out to the baseboard...not good.

Answer (score 0):

That is entirely up to you. Everybody has a different perspective of look. I would paint it the same as the baseboard. However, if the gap was too wide, I would have found a way to force the baseboard into the wall better. Another nail, a wall anchor....something to reduce the gap.